# GeoCoordinate System.FormatException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, coordinates, tombstone

I have a viewmodel which contains a System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate property which is marked as [DataMember] like so:

```
[DataMember]
public GeoCoordinate Location
{
    get
    {
        return _location;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_location != value)
        {
            _location = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Location");
        }
    }
}
```

I have a collection of a this viewmodel, and for every item of the collection I am getting:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

The interesting part is that this only occurs when I am navigating back, but somewhere before OnNavigatedTo event fires.

Is this a known issue? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `GeoCoordinate` is serializable by the `DataContractSerializer`?

Try to build a custom `GeoCoordinate` type: write a simple class with two double latitude/longitude properties, a `BuildFromGeoCoordinate()` and a `ToGeoCoordinate()` method to convert from/to `GeoCoordinate`, and check if the error still happens.

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well, to create a custom class for it, I just though there is another way